# Core Data Fetch Relationship not working

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2

I have a problem with fetching data from relationships.
I have a survey and i want to save the answers, the userIds and the results to core data and fetch the data at the next start of the app.
They are in arrays. 
Each of it will be turned to a NSManagedObject "Wert", into the attribute "valueInt" if it is a result and "valueString" if it is an answer or an userId.

```
extension Wert {

@NSManaged var valueInt: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var valueString: String?
}
```

Afterwards it will be saved on the NSManagedObject "Message", as a NSSet on answers, results or userIds.

```
extension Message {

@NSManaged var absenderId: String?
@NSManaged var absenderName: String?
@NSManaged var datum: NSDate?
@NSManaged var gruppenId: String?
@NSManaged var image: NSData?
@NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var messageId: String?
@NSManaged var question: String?
@NSManaged var sound: NSData?
@NSManaged var text: String?
@NSManaged var answers: NSSet?
@NSManaged var results: NSSet?
@NSManaged var userIDs: NSSet?
}
```

I think that this is working, because after the "addObjectsFromArray" AnswersSet contains some values.

```
func saveCoreData(AbsenderName: String, AbsenderID: String,  Text: String?, Image: NSData?, Datum: NSDate, Latitude: Double?, Longitude: Double?, MessageId: String, Sound: NSData?, question: String?, answers : [String]?, results : [Int]?, userIDs: [String]?) {

    let newMessage = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Message", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    newMessage.setValue(AbsenderID, forKey: "absenderId")
    newMessage.setValue(AbsenderName, forKey: "absenderName")
    newMessage.setValue(Text, forKey: "text")
    newMessage.setValue(Image, forKey: "image")
    newMessage.setValue(Latitude, forKey: "latitude")
    newMessage.setValue(Longitude, forKey: "longitude")
    newMessage.setValue(Datum, forKey: "datum")
    newMessage.setValue(GroupId, forKey: "gruppenId")
    newMessage.setValue(MessageId, forKey: "messageId")
    newMessage.setValue(Sound, forKey: "sound")

    if question != nil && answers != nil && results != nil && userIDs != nil {

        newMessage.setValue(question, forKey: "question")

        var AnswersArray = [NSManagedObject]()
        var ResultsArray = [NSManagedObject]()
        var userIDsArray = [NSManagedObject]()

        for var index = 0; index < answers?.count ; ++index {
        let newWert = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Wert", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        newWert.setValue(answers![index], forKey: "valueString")
        AnswersArray.append(newWert)
        }


        for var index = 0; index < results?.count ; ++index {
            let newWert = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Wert", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
            newWert.setValue(results![index], forKey: "valueInt")
            ResultsArray.append(newWert)
        }

        for var index = 0; index < userIDs?.count ; ++index {
            let newWert = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Wert", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
            newWert.setValue(userIDs![index], forKey: "valueString")
            userIDsArray.append(newWert)
        }



        let answersSet = newMessage.mutableSetValueForKey("answers")
        let resultsSet = newMessage.mutableSetValueForKey("results")
        let userIdsSet = newMessage.mutableSetValueForKey("userIDs")

        answersSet.addObjectsFromArray(AnswersArray)
        resultsSet.addObjectsFromArray(ResultsArray)
        userIdsSet.addObjectsFromArray(userIDsArray)


    }



    do {
       try context.save()

    }
    catch _ {

        print("Error")
    }

}
```

But when i try to fetch the saved values with mutableSetValueForKey(), they contain 0 objects. Everything else is working.

```
func loadCoreData() -> Int {

    var x : [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Message")
    request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "gruppenId = %@", GroupId)
    let sort1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "datum", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort1]



    do {

        x = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

            for (var i = 0 ; i < x.count; ++i ) {




                let Absender = x[i].valueForKey("absenderName") as! String
                let AbsenderID = x[i].valueForKey("absenderId") as! String
                let Text : String? = x[i].valueForKey("text") as? String
                let Image : NSData? = x[i].valueForKey("image") as? NSData

                let Sound : NSData? = x[i].valueForKey("sound") as? NSData

                let Date : NSDate = x[i].valueForKey("datum") as! NSDate
                let GruppenID : String = x[i].valueForKey("gruppenId") as! String
                let MessageID : String = x[i].valueForKey("messageId") as! String

                let longitude : Double? = x[i].valueForKey("longitude") as? Double
                let latitude : Double? = x[i].valueForKey("latitude") as? Double

                let question : String? = x[i].valueForKey("question") as? String
               let answers = x[i].mutableSetValueForKey("answers") as? NSMutableSet
                let results = x[i].mutableSetValueForKey("results") as? NSMutableSet
                let userIds = x[i].mutableSetValueForKey("userIDs") as? NSMutableSet

   }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answers, results etc. are one-to-many relationships. In this case, it is always safer (and more concise) to simply set the to-one relationship.

Thus, rather than maintaining a clumsy array and dealing with `mutableSetValueForKey`, you could simply use the inverse relationship:

```
newWert.message = newMessage
```

NB: Please adopt the convention of using `lowerCase` variable names to avoid confusion with class names.

NB2: I strongly advise using `NSManagedObject` subclasses and using dot.notation to set and get values. With one stroke, all the variables you define in your many lines of code above would become utterly superfluous.

Comment: Ok, I changed that, But how can i do that in the loadCoreData method? I changed `var x : [Message] = [Message]()` and ` x = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Message]` , but when i try to do `x[i].absenderName' or 'x[i].answers` , i get the error message: fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Comment: You coming from Java? I haven't done a for loop like this in years. Use fast enumeration: `for message in x { message.absenderName = whatever }`.